# Why is this string immutable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Why does the code give the error - Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat: ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSTextTestingResult *match in matches) {
    <omitted>
    NSMutableString *value;
    value = (NSMutableString *)[response stringWithRange:range];
    if ([dict objectForKey:@"traveler"])
        [dict objectForKey:@"traveler"] appendFormat:@"%@", value];     //  Errors here

[dict setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

Value is being created as a `_NSCFString`.

Comment: Because response is an NSString and stringWithRange: also returns an NSString...

Comment: @Mario Aha. I see that `subStringWithRange:` returns NSString now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `[response stringWithRange:range]` returns an immutable `NSString *`, and casting doesn't make it become mutable.

You want `value = [[response stringWithRange:range] mutableCopy];`.

Note that if you're not using ARC, you need to remember to release the `mutableCopy`. Although the return value of `[response stringWithRange:range]` is autoreleased, the `mutableCopy` is not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can cast a string to mutable like that.

You need to do it like this:

```
ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[ms setString:immutableString];
```

Oops, wrong again: the way the subclass works you should be able to do it like this more simply:

```
ms = [NSMutableString stringWithString: immutableString];
```

Comment: my bad been a while since i looked at the docs i assumed there was a stringWithString but apparently not, it takes some more gymnastics

Comment: OK. I'll give that a try. Is your `ms` my `value` ?